# Convert Excel to MongoDB

Tags: python, excel, mongodb

I want to move data from Excel files into MongoDB. The Excel data is updated daily so I want to add the new data on daily reads. I'm using Python and so far have only been trying to make a Python dictionary object to represent the Excel data just to understand how MongoDB is storing its data but feel that I misunderstand some vital points.

The situation I want to solve:

```
I have MANY Excel files.   
    Each Excel file has MANY sheets,   
        Each sheet has MANY columns.
```

How do I repeat the reads daily on the same Excel files and add any new data to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

As a point of order, I think you are asking the wrong question here.

What you likely want is to **read** data from a spreadsheet (or spreadsheets as you mention) and then **construct** insertion of that data into MongoDB via the programming interface of your choice.

You don't mention a language you are using or what you have tried, so it's hard to advise further. However you most certainly don't want BSON documents, that appears to be a misunderstanding of what you need to do.

If you are talking about how you structure your collection with data from an Excel sheet, then that is a little to broad. You can do it how you want to.

Possibly think of re-structuring your question to something specific, as I don't see in it's form how anyone can help without clearly seeing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, im not sure what im doing so it is great that you make me think more about it. I have made some changes, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Well, now we know you're using Python. That's a start. If you're not using [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.2) to read the Excel data, you definitely want to. You probably want to look at [PyMongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/python/) for writing the data into MongoDB.